# Can't Update "data-attribute" Value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

The upload bar needs to be updated and i think everything is true but I can not update the `data-value`.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="Result_Success" class="progress-Bar" data-value="0"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
success: function (response) {
      $("#Result_Success").data('value', response["yuzdelik"]);
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Though the currently accepted answer (*KongFB*'s one) is technically not wrong, the one of *Useless Code* should be considered the accepted one for it uses the `dataset` property which was introduced for exactly this purpose ... "reading from" and "writing to" element-node related data-values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need

`javascript
$("#Result_Success").attr('data-value', response["yuzdelik"]);`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to access the element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property directly to change it. To do so, you need to get a reference to the raw DOM node, not wrapped by a jQuery object. You can get the raw DOM node by using jQuery's [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method `$("#Result_Success").get(0)`, or using jQuery's [array-like nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599071/array-like-objects-in-javascript) using `$("#Result_Success")[0]`, as I do in the example below.

```js
function setResponse (response) {
      $("#Result_Success")[0].dataset.value = response["yuzdelik"];
}


let val = 0;
let timer = setInterval(function () {
    setResponse({yuzdelik: val});
    if (val >= 100) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      val += 25;
    }
  }, 500);
```

```css
#prog {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
#Result_Success {
  height: 20px;
  background: #0f0;
}

#Result_Success[data-value="0"] {
  width: 0%;
}

#Result_Success[data-value="25"] {
  width: 25%;
}

#Result_Success[data-value="50"] {
  width: 50%;
}

#Result_Success[data-value="75"] {
  width: 75%;
}

#Result_Success[data-value="100"] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prog">
<div id="Result_Success" class="progress-Bar" data-value="0"></div>
</div>
```

The reason that using `$("#Result_Success").data()` doesn't work is that it does not actually modify `data-` attributes. jQuery stores data set with `.data` inside itself. jQuery does this instead of modifying the element attributes to avoid [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). Circular references on DOM elements aren't really a big deal these days, but back when IE was more relevant they were, because in older versions of IE (especially IE6) they [would cause memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092619/precise-explanation-of-javascript-dom-circular-reference-issue#10093481) when you removed the element from the DOM.

It can get a little confusing that this is what it is actually doing because jQuery will [pull any `data-` attributes into its own internal data](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5). The documentation states:

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

Comment: @OnunBununEvlari2 ... Though the currently accepted answer (*KongFB*'s one) is technically not wrong, the above one should be considered the accepted one for it uses the `dataset` property which was introduced for exactly this purpose ... "reading from" and "writing to" element-node related data-values.