# Trying to understand what is actually memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, vue.js

I am pretty new to frontend development, currently learning Vue.js. When I follow its [tutorial](http://vuejs.org/guide/overview.html), there is one paragraph that says:

> This looks pretty similar to just rendering a template, but Vue.js has
>   done a lot of work under the hood. The data and the DOM are now
>   linked, and everything is now reactive. How do we know? Just open up
>   your browser developer console and **modify exampleData.name**. You should
>   see the rendered example above update accordingly.

```
<!-- this is our View -->
<div id="example-1">
  Hello {{ name }}!
</div>
// this is our Model
var exampleData = {
  name: 'Vue.js'
}

// create a Vue instance, or, a "ViewModel"
// which links the View and the Model
var exampleVM = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: exampleData
})
```

In the console, instead of modifying exampleData.name I give exampleData another object like `exampleData = {}`. Now, the reference has been modified to point to elsewhere, and it seems there is no reference to the original data(`exampleData.name`), **I wonder if this is a memory leak? If not, what kind of situation is a true memory leak?**

Comment: It's only a memory leak if a chunk of memory is still in use but you can't/won't actually access it. Whether it's a leak in this case all depends on how Vue.js does things under the hood.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks. Could you show me a way how I can reuse/rerefernce that memory?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't used Vue.js. My guess would be you can still access it through `exampleVM`.

Comment: "*it seems there is no reference to the original data*" - surely `exampleVM` holds one, otherwise it's rather pointless to pass it in. And given that it *still needs it*, that's not a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: @Bergi Sorry I did not quite get your point. I mean how can I get the reference to the data mapping to that DOM again. And another question is how to tell if this is a real memory leaking

Comment: @MikeC I tried, but this time, the text on the page does not change even I give original data {name:"Vue.js"} to that exampleVM

Comment: @Kuan: I don't think you can get back the reference. Why don't you simply keep it in the first place, instead of ovewriting `exampleData`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, keep it in first place is for sure. I just want to use my scenario to ask if that operation can lead to memory leaking

Comment: @Kuan: No, there's no memory leak. You should have a look at http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html though.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, what part of that link related to this question?

Comment: @Kuan: The lifecycle, especially the `.$data` property and `.$destroy` method.

Comment: @Bergi  OK, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have memory leaks (in the traditional sense) because it has automatic garbage collection. The JS interpreter records a **reference count** for every object (including numbers, strings, etc.). When the reference count hits 0, the object will be deleted (usually using a 'mark-and-sweep' algorithm).

So, in your example, exampleData.name is actually a reference to some object (number, string, JS object, etc.), and when you enter exampleData.name = {}, two things happen (let's assume exampleData.name was originally equal to the string "oldname"):

1. '{}' creates a new object with a single reference count (exampleData.name now points to it)
2. The string object "oldname" now has a reference count of 0, because its only reference, exampleData.name, not points to something else. Now, the next time the garbage collector runs, exampleData.name will be deleted.

Having said that, it is possible to unintentionally waste memory (though not a memory leak in the traditional sense) in certain JavaScript scenarios, like the following closure:

```
function wastefulFunc(){
    var giantObj = {};
    ///fill giantObj up with thousands of entries
    function closureFunc(){}
    return closureFunc;
}
var waste = wastefulFunc();
```

Even though it doesn't look like it, giantObj will be kept around for as long as the 'waste' var exists, because the scope created by closureFunc sets the reference count of giantObj to 1.

As for a 'true' memory leak, consider a language like C++, which doesn't have automatic garbage collection:

```
void leakFunc(){ Foo* f = new Foo; }
```

The code above creates a pointer, f, which points to an explicitly allocated Foo object. As soon as the function finishes, however, the variable f will be destroyed, but we have no way of referencing the memory it pointed to. Since C++ does not have automatic garbage collection, the allocated memory that f pointed to will forever be marked as allocated, and we CANNOT get free it, because we have lost any way of referencing it! Therefore, the memory has 'leaked' out of the pool of memory available to our program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170415/do-you-know-what-may-cause-memory-leaks-in-javascript?rq=1